# The completeness of the domain of the Neumann Laplace operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n,$ be an open bounded set with smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. By $\partial_\eta$ denote the normal derivative.

Consider the Laplace operator defined by
$$
\begin{split}
\Delta :\; &D(A)\subset L^2(\Omega) \longrightarrow L^2(\Omega)\\
&u\mapsto \Delta u,
\end{split}
$$
where
$$
D(A):=\{u \in H^2(\Omega), \quad \partial_\eta u=0, \ \text{on}\; \partial \Omega \}.
$$
As I understand the domain $D(A)$ equipped with the graph norm
$$
\Vert u \Vert_{D(A)}:=\Vert \Delta u\Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}+\Vert u \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
is a Banach space.

I'm trying to prove that the domain $D(A)$ equipped with the norm $\Vert \; \Vert_{H^2(\Omega)}$ is also a Banach space.

My guess is that since $D(A)$ can be seen as the kernel of the trace operator and by continuity of the latter. Then, $(D(A),\Vert \; \Vert_{H^2(\Omega)})$ is a Banach space. Is this claim true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Since the trace operator is continuous, its kernel $D(A)$ is a closed subspace of $H^2$, i.e., a Banach space.